# CSP warning when using FontAwesome web fonts (Kit)

Tags: css, font-awesome, content-security-policy

According to FontAwesome's documentation for V6:

> Using Web Fonts with CSS? You don't need to worry about CSP issues. These workarounds aren't needed.

I load FontAwesome like so:

`<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/589f449313.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

My CSP is:

`Content-Security-Policy: default-src data: 'self' https://*.bootstrap.com https://*.jsdelivr.net https://*.fontawesome.com https://fonts.googleapis.com https://fonts.gstatic.com https://code.jquery.com; form-action 'self'; upgrade-insecure-requests`

However, the FontAwesome icons are not loading and I receive this error in the inspector:

`Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src data: 'self' https://*.bootstrap.com https://*.jsdelivr.net https://*.fontawesome.com https://fonts.googleapis.com https://fonts.gstatic.com https://code.jquery.com". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-vbZVW+MEGpqM/MTrc0cuTI1eza7x/JNIBG8uVXROwnE='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'style-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.`

I am unsure what else I should do, as FontAwesome's documentation states that I should not need to do anything special in the CSP for inline styles.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72940414/insertbefore-and-appendchild-in-font-awesome-kit-version-5-15-4-causing-csp-is/73025556#73025556)

I've not used the kit, but the single files instead:

```
<link href="~/fontawesome6/css/brands.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/fontawesome6/css/solid.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/fontawesome6/css/v5-font-face.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/fontawesome6/js/fontawesome.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/fontawesome6/js/brands.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/fontawesome6/js/solid.min.js"></script>
```

In that way it was possible to better see with the Chrome Dev Tools, where to handle. I've added one by one the sha-* values suggested by Chrome.

I did not add `unsafe-inline` anywhere

My CSP code-block:

```
context.Response.Headers.Add(
"Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only",
"default-src 'none' ;" +
"script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://kit.fontawesome.com/ ;" +
"style-src 'self' ;" +
"img-src 'self' data:  ;" +
"font-src 'self' https://ka-f.fontawesome.com/  ;" +
"media-src 'self' data: ; " +
"frame-src 'self' ;" +
"connect-src 'self' ws: https://ka-f.fontawesome.com/ ;" +
"object-src 'none' ;" +
"base-uri 'self' data: ;" +
"report-uri /cspreport ;"
);
```

In the `style-src` you have to add your `sha256-*`

Hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

Your problem concern inline style. May be it's in your html page, or from the script. try somthing like this :

```
Content-Security-Policy: default-src data: 'self' https://*.bootstrap.com https://*.jsdelivr.net https://*.fontawesome.com https://fonts.googleapis.com https://fonts.gstatic.com https://code.jquery.com; form-action 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; upgrade-insecure-requests
```

you may be need to add the externals uri you use.

Comment: From [content-security-policy.com - `unsafe-inline`](https://content-security-policy.com/unsafe-inline/): *"**Warning**
Except for one very specific case, you should avoid using the `unsafe-inline` keyword in your CSP policy. As you might guess it is generally unsafe to use `unsafe-inline`."* and ***"The `unsafe-inline` keyword annuls most of the security benefits that `Content-Security-Policy` provide."***